# requestAnimationFrame [now] vs performance.now() time discrepancy

Tags: javascript, timing, requestanimationframe, performance.now

Assumptions: rAF `now` time is calculated at the time the set of callbacks are all triggered. Therefore  any blocking that happens before the first callback of that frame is called doesn't affect the rAF `now` and it's accurate--at least for that first callback.

Any performance.now() measurements made before a rAF set is triggered should be earlier than rAF `now`.

Test: Record `before` (a baseline time before *anything* happens). Set the next rAF. Compare rAF `now` and actual `performance.now()` to `before` to see how different they are.

Expected results:

```js
var before = performance.now(), frames = ["with blocking", "with no blocking"], calls = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(function frame(rAFnow) {
  var actual = performance.now();
  console.log("frame " + (calls + 1) + " " + frames[calls] + ":");
  console.log("before frame -> rAF now: " + (rAFnow - before));
  console.log("before frame -> rAF actual: " + (actual - before));

  if (++calls < frames.length) { before = actual; requestAnimationFrame(frame); }
});

// blocking
for (var i = 0, l = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    l += i;
}
```

Observations: When there is blocking before the frame starts, the rAF `now` time is at times incorrect, even for that first frame. Sometimes the first frame's `now` is actually an earlier time than the recorded `before` time.

Whether there is blocking happening before the frame or not, every so often the in-frame time `rAFnow` will be earlier than the pre-frame time `before`--even when I setup the rAF *after* I take my first measurement. This can also happen without any blocking whatsoever, though this is rarer.

(I get a timing error on the first blocking frame most of the time. Getting an issue on the others is rarer, but does happen occasionally if you try running it a few times.)

With more extensive testing, I've found bad times with blocking prior to callback: 1% from 100 frames, no blocking: 0.21645021645021645% from ~400 frames, seemingly caused by opening a window or some other potentially CPU-intensive action by the user.

So it's fairly rare, but the problem is this shouldn't happen at all. If you want to do useful things with them, simulating time, animation, etc., then you need those times to make sense.

I've taken into account what people have said, but maybe I am still not understanding how things work. If this is all per-spec, I'd love some psuedo-code to solidify it in my mind.

And more importantly, if anyone has any suggestions for how I could get around these issues, that would be awesome. The only thing I can think of is taking my own `performance.now()` measurement every frame and using that--but it seems a bit wasteful, having it effectively run twice every frame, on top of any triggered events and so on.

Comment: I added a halting state to your snippet. Feel free to rollback, but this way the code actually finishes at some point :).

Comment: No, that's cool. Thanks, @MikeMcCaughan.

Answer (score 10):

#### Please see the more recent answers below for some very detailed analysis of where the timer values come from.

---

The timestamp passed in to the `requestAnimationFrame()` callback is the time of the beginning of the animation frame. Multiple callbacks being invoked during the same frame all receive the same timestamp. Thus, it would be really weird if `performance.now()` returned a time *before* the parameter value, but not really weird for it to be *after* that.

[Here's the relevant specification:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/webappapis.html#animation-frames)

> When the user agent is to run the animation frame callbacks for a Document document with a timestamp *now*, it must run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the value returned by the document object’s hidden attribute is true, abort these steps. [PAGE-VISIBILITY]
> 2. Let callbacks be a list of the entries in document’s list of animation frame callbacks, in the order in which they were added to the list.
> 3. Set document’s list of animation frame callbacks to the empty list.
> 4. For each entry in callbacks, in order: invoke the Web IDL callback function, passing *now* as the only argument, and if an exception is thrown, report the exception.

So you've registered a callback (let's say just one) for the next animation frame. Tick tick tick, BOOM, time for that animation frame to happen:

1. The JavaScript runtime makes a note of the time and labels that *now*.
2. The runtime makes a temporary copy of the list of registered animation frame callbacks, and clears the actual list (so that they're not accidentally invoked if things take so long that the next animation frame comes around).
3. The list has just one thing in it: your callback. The system invokes that with *now* as the parameter.
4. Your callback starts running. Maybe it's never been run before, so the JavaScript optimizer may need to do some work. Or maybe the operating system switches threads to some other system process, like starting up a disk buffer flush or handling some network traffic, or any of dozens of other things.
5. Oh right, your callback. The browser gets the CPU again and your callback code starts running.
6. Your code calls `performance.now()` and compares it to the *now* value passed in as a parameter.

Because a brief but non-ignorable amount of time may pass between step 1 and step 6, the return value from `performance.now()` may indicate that a couple of microseconds, or even more than a couple, have elapsed. **That is perfectly normal behavior.**

Comment: Are you saying that _any_ callback, even non-rAF ones will have the same performance.now() value? That doesn't seem to be the case.

If you mean multiple rAF callbacks, I'm only using a single rAF.

Comment: I've made edits to better explain what's happening. (I wasn't sure if you'd get notified?)

Comment: @Whothehellisthat no no no.  When the event occurs internal to the JavaScript runtime that triggers the processing of callbacks for an animation frame, the timestamp is noted **once** at the beginning of that process. Each callback registered by `requestAnimationFrame()` is passed exactly the same time value. It really has nothing to do with subsequent calls to `performance.now()`, except that they will obviously all happen *after* that initial time is collected.

Comment: Depending on what's happening on your system (other processes, operating system work, etc), it's entirely possible for some microseconds to elapse between the animation frame internals collect the frame start timestamp and the time at which the code in your callback runs. In particular, the system **does not** pass the result of calling `performance.now()` to each callback. Thus, even if there's only one registered callback, it is not surprising that it's parameter is a smaller number than what's returned by `performance.now()`.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat answer extended a little.

Comment: That all sounds logical. The problem is, it's up to 16 milliseconds out--not a few microseconds, but a whole frame! And that's just the first thing is does in the rAF, before any processing is done.

Comment: Now heavily editing the question to pare it down to the important parts.

Comment: Edits done, basically rewritten from scratch to be much clearer and more focussed.

Comment: Any thoughts? You've been very helpful to me on exploring what is actually going on here.

Comment: Well, ultimately neither the browser nor the underlying operating system is a truly real-time platfurm. Real-time systems have all sorts of ways of controlling latency and preemption priority, but between the OS and the browser (and, for that matter, the JavaScript interpreter itself) you're far from that. And, of course, you may be encountering legit bugs in the browser(s) you're testing.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough. But to me, that's the whole point of using Date.now or performance.now or rAF's now--you can make calculations based on the correct time at runtime. I'm guessing it probably is a bug, as you say. Otherwise what would be the point of rAF now. I'll just take my own performance.now measurement each frame, I guess.

Comment: Question: can the timeStamp argument received by the callback ever be equal to zero?  It seems that it could be zero for the first animation frame, but I have never seen that happen.  Then again, I've have not tested the idea fully.

Comment: You said `it would be really weird if performance.now() returned a time before the parameter value`, but the whole problem is the initial `before` is larger than `rAFnow` passed by requestAnimationFrame, which is because `timestamp` passed by requestAnimationFrame is not made when people would think it would be.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue on chrome, where calls to `performance.now ()` would return a higher value than the `now` value passed into subsequent callbacks made by `window.requestAnimationFrame ()`

My workaround was to set the `before` using the `now` passed to the callback in the first `window.requestAnimationFrame ()` **rather** than `performance.now ()`.  It seems that using *only one of the two functions* to measure time guarantees progressing values.

I hope this helps anyone else suffering through this bug.

Answer (score 3):

## General description

I did a in-depth investigation of the issue that `requestAnimationFrame` can report time earlier than previously invoked `performance.now()`, even with high-precision timers (when COOP/COEP is enabled). For example, when your app is under heavy CPU load, the following code:

```js
let prev = 0
function onFrame(t) {
    if (t < prev) {
        console.log("FAIL!", t - prev)
    }
    prev = performance.now() 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
```

Can report:

```
FAIL! -1.4840001144402777
FAIL! -0.6779997711182659
FAIL! -1.3689998474110325
FAIL! -0.5829999618545116
FAIL! -0.4240000762947602
FAIL! -1.018999790190719
FAIL! -0.056999980926775606
FAIL! -5.993999904632801
FAIL! -0.26899996185238706
FAIL! -0.9029996757490153
FAIL! -1.6019999237068987
....
```

It looks, like this is the **CORRECT** behavior, at least in Chrome. Handling of events, animation frames, and scheduling tasks is an implementation detail of every browser. We did an in-depth analysis of how Chrome handles these things. Other browsers' behavior might differ.

## Events scheduling in Chrome

The following graph shows an example order of tasks per frame with the assumptions that all the frame tasks can be executed within that frame and the application runs with native FPS.

```
             ║    Frame 1     ║    Frame 2     ║    Frame 3     ║ ...
 Idle time   ║█            ███║██         █████║████           █║ ...
 Other tasks ║ █          █   ║  █       █     ║    █        █  ║ ...
 I/O Events  ║  ██   █████    ║      ████      ║     █   ████   ║ ...
 RAF         ║    ███         ║   ███          ║      ███       ║ ...
 GPU         ║      ████      ║     ███        ║        ██████  ║ ...
```

A few things should be noted here:

- **Frame start idle time.** At the beginning of almost every frame, there will be an idle time
  of up to a few milliseconds (we've observed idle times between 0 ms and 4 ms). This time is
  likely caused by frames being synchronized with the screen refresh rate, while the tasks are
  performed by the Chrome task scheduler, which is not fired at the synchronization points. To
  learn more, see [this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=607650). It
  is not clear whether Chrome considers this a bug or if they will ever fix it.
- **Other tasks.** These are Chrome-internal tasks. For example, before every animation frame,
  Chrome performs some preparation work, which in most cases is very short (we've observed times
  between 20 μs and 40 μs). At the end of the frame, Chrome performs pre-paint, layout,
  layerize, and commit jobs, which, in the case of a WebGL applications as ours (when no HTML elements
  are on the stage), are also short, ranging between 0.1 ms and 0.5 ms.
- **I/O Events.** Events such as mouse down/up/move can be scheduled before or after the RAF
  callback. Some of these events might originate in the previous frame, and their handling might
  be scheduled for the next frame by Chrome.
- **RAF.** The RAF (Request Animation Frame) callback, which in case of a WebGL application would trigger per-frame functions, such
  as animations, display object layout recomputation, WebGL buffer updates, and invoking WebGL
  draw calls.
- **GPU.** The GPU-related work starts at the end of the RAF callback, as soon as the first
  WebGL calls are issued. It is performed in parallel with the rest of the RAF callback, I/O
  events, and other tasks performed by Chrome.

In case the total time of all the per-frame tasks is longer than the frame duration with the native refresh rate, some frames might be skipped, and a very interesting time report behavior can be observed. Let's consider the following events graph:

```
             ║ Real frame 1 work  ┆          Real frame 2 work         ┆        ...
             ║    Frame 1     ║   ┆Frame 2     ║ Frame 3 (skip) ║    Frame 4     ║  ...
 Idle time   ║███             ║   ┆            ║                ║      ┆         ║  ...
 Other tasks ║   █            ║  █┆            ║                ║     █┆         ║  ...
 RAF         ║    ██████████  ║   ┆  ██████████████████████████████    ┆ ██████████ ...
 I/O Events  ║              █████ ┆██          ║                ║  ██  ┆█        ║  ...
 GPU         ║              ███   ┆            ║                ║     █┆         ║  ...
```

A few things should be noted here:

- **Frame start idle time.** As previously mentioned, we can observe an idle time at the
  beginning of the first frame. The Chrome task scheduler rendered the previous frame in time,
  so there was no pressure to start the next tasks immediately. However, there is no idle time
  present in the next frames as their computations took longer than the native frame duration.
- **Frame times.** Even if the real computation time can exceed the time of a few frames issued
  with the native refresh rate, the frames are always scheduled with the native refresh rate
  time. Thus, some of these frames might be skipped, like frame 3 in the example above.
- **RAF start time.** When the RAF callback is called, it is provided with the frame start time.
  However, this time might be smaller than the time reported by performance.now(). For example,
  in the graph above, the third call to the RAF callback will report the beginning time of frame
  4, even though it was performed in the middle of frame 4. If we measured the time at the end
  of the second RAF callback with performance.now(), this time would be bigger than the time
  reported by the third RAF callback.

Comment: This is extremely useful information. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

> Assumptions: rAF `now` time is calculated at the time the set of callbacks are all triggered.

That's the issue. Even if it's what the specs ask for, it's not what browsers do. In systems supporting VSync, `now` will be the time when the monitor sent its last VSync open signal. It is not linked to the CPU nor to your JS execution.

The browser will assume that until it hasn't received a new VSync signal, it still has time to send new data to the compositor, which will actually send it to the monitor the next frame. Basically, it has a one frame buffer<sup>1</sup>.
So in the case of a long frame, the one where you do block the JS thread, it will try to produce the next frame fast enough so that both frames can be passed to the monitor in time.

For instance if we take the following diagram,

```
VSync open signals      :  |-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|----------
JS callbacks            :  |long-frame------------|short-frame |next-frame----   |...
Presentation to monitor :  [previous frame  ][long frame      ][short frame     ][next frame
```

we can see that the *short frame* would still have time to be presented to the monitor in its own presentation frame, and that the *next frame* would even have caught up with the delay. But the `now` passed in *short frame*  would indeed report a time before the end of *long frame*.

If *short frame*  takes too long to be rendered in its own presentation frame, it will take the slot of *next frame*, and its own presentation frame would be skipped.

<sup>1. There are some APIs that are able to bypass the compositor and thus this one frame buffer, for instance canvas2D has a `desynchronized` option, but this is only available in some systems.</sup>